# Switching between iOS versions in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

In Xcode 5 you could easily switch between iOS versions inside the toolbar:

[image]

But in Xcode 6 this feature is missing:

[image]

Any solution for that?

Comment: go to Preference/Downloads and download the other iOS version of the simulator

Comment: @tkanzakic They are not available for download when I looked. Perhaps this is a beta issue.

Comment: I have downloaded, but that doesn't change anything

Comment: I don't know, could be, I am at work right now and only have the beta release at home :(, but in the stable version this is how you "solve" this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this change is just a beta issue or a new design decision from Apple but you can still switch between iOS versions. Apple added a new devices menu to Xcode which you can rename or delete existing simulators or add new ones. Open devices menu from `Window->Devices` and give appropriate names for the simulators like "iPhone 5 (7.0)".